# Database for Embedded Linux, and Architecture

Tags: linux, database, sqlite, embedded

below is architecture of my applications.

sensor↔parser app↔database↔application1↔ethernet↔server

application2 and application3 are same level of application1.

database = sqlite3

problem is that too many transaction occured on database system.

parser app and applications are queries whole range of database for checking any differences every second.

so i would like to change architecture or database.

is there any database which has better performance than sqlite3?
or which part do i have to change?

Comment: If that particular query is slow, it's likely that it is written inefficiently, or that the DB does not have useful indexes. Show the database schema and the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would switch out sqlite3 in favor of MySQL or PostgreSQL, those database systems are meant to handle multiple clients where as sqlite3 won't be able to do this because everything is stored in a single file. Each (write) access therefore has to block the entire database instead of only a single row of the table in question.